# Resource allocation using genetic algorithm and matlab

Tags: algorithm, genetic

i am working in resource allocation problem, in this i have total 50000 resource and i want to distribulte it on 6 module. objective is

```
f(i)=1-exp(-b(i)*w(i)); for i=1 to 6
g(i)=1+2*exp(-b(i)*w(i)); for i=1 to 6
ff=(c1-c2)*a(i)*v(i)*f(i)/g(i)+c2*a(i)+c3*w(i);  for i=1 to 6
```

and a(i),b(i),c1,c2,c3 and v(i) is known

and consrtaont is

w(i)<=w whare i=1 to 6

w(i)>=0 and

r(i)=1-exp(-b(i)*w(i))/1+2*exp(-b(i)*w(i))>=0.9; ie r(i) of each module is >= 0.9

so i need W(i) i=1 to 6 and total w is 50000.

Please any one tell me how i will do using genetic algo.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Having the evaluation function is not enough to determine what the genetic algorithm will look like, because even though the evaluation function is very important, it is not the only part of your problem. In order to fully evaluate your problem, one needs to know at least the following:

1. What are the restrictions on each module and in the total
   distribution? For instance, is there a capacity limit for each
   module?
2. What kind of resources we are dealing with? Are there
   dependencies between resources, either function or temporal?
3. What kind of problem are we dealing with? Are all resources to be
   allocated or do we intend to use them to perform a certain task
   (hence, we will neeed specific types of resources in each module)?

Assuming you need all the resources allocated, the simplest (and maybe dumbest) solution is to encode the module to which each resource will be designated into the chromosome and have a 50.000 long string of 1's, 2's, 3's, ... and 6's. All the bit string operators may be applied to this solution with the minor changes applicable, of course.

Since working with a 50.000 characters long string would be though, we need alternative. If there are any numeric parameters on each resource, we can consider creating a representation that is made of the group centers and cluster the resources according to their proximity to each center. Nevertheless, there should be a meaningful transposition of the resources into the multidimensional real numbers set. In order to create that, we need to know more about the resources themselves.

Comment: Actually my problem is i want to distribute all resource(50000) to 6 module restriction is reliability must be 0.9 using r(i)=1-exp(-b(i)*w(i))/1+2*exp(-b(i)*w(i))>=0.9 will calculate it. and w(i)<=50000 and >=0.

Comment: I have edited my response to add new alternatives, but the questions I asked still remain the same.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much for your response. no restriction, just want allocation during module testing considering cost, testing effort and reliability. reliability should be >= 0.9 out of 1 and i have total 50000 efforts.i need each modules effort, cost and reliability should be >=0.9. in original question i wrote objective function and constraints.